# Passing an icon (component) to a child component?

Tags: vuejs3

I have an array of objects which I pass to a component to render out:

```
const stats = ref([
    { title: 'Series', value: props.data.series, icon: 'CheckCircleIcon' },
    ...
```

I wish to pass an icon from hero icons.

So, in the child component, I hope to render it by (in a loop):

```
 <component :is="item.icon" class="w-7" />
```

Obviously this won't work, as I need to import the icon:

```
import { CheckCircleIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline';
```

My questions are:

1. Where to import the icon?
2. How to pass icon from an array of objects?

Comment: import statement goes in the child component.  If `:is="item.icon"` matches the name of the imported heroicon component, it should just work.